# .Net Micro Framework - String to float

Tags: c#, string, floating-point, .net-micro-framework

How do I convert a `string` to a `float` in .Net Micro Framework?

String is formatted as: `"38.5000"`

Comment: Does `float.Parse` not exist in the Micro framework? How about `double.Parse`?

Comment: @JonSkeet `float.Parse` does not exist but `double.Parse` did, thanks Jon.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is, *you don't*, use `Double` instead - `double.Parse`.
A great thanks to Jon Skeet for helping me on the way.

Answer (score -1):

```
float f = Convert.ToSingle("38.5");
```